# Fill in the "To:" field from the URL in Gmail

Tags: gmail, url

I know that I can quickly launch New message dialog by going to https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new. I often send a file to a list of my colleagues so it would be nice to have the `To:` field prefilled with their emails.

Is it possible to go further and fill in the `To:` field with a list of addresses?

Comment: no, but there are programs, maybe  wavget pasteitin where you can click a button and it automatically types or pastes stuff in

Comment: and one sees that the new message dialog thing can be done, by having clicked new and seen that URL appear in the address bar, so one can know they're equivalent.. There is nothing like that with the To textbox.   And  you can be reasonably sure that gmail hasn't written an entry on their web server that says take any email addresses specified in the url and add them to the to box. Also if it had that they could make it so an email can be sent by just going to a url, and then it'd encourage people to use gmail accounts to spam people and google wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Pulled this from Stack Overflow... this URL seems to do the trick

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=someone@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY&bcc=someone.else@example.com
```

We're integrating with Slack and have a bot letting us know when new emails to our Google Groups come in. I was looking for this same thing to add a hyperlink to the Slack notification that allows us to quickly reply to the sender via Gmail (instead of mailto trying to use Outlook or another default mail client).

Haven't found a way to pre-fill the "To" field in the nice Gmail pop-up composer though... only through this full screen option.

[Stack overflow source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548570/url-to-compose-a-message-in-gmail-with-full-gmail-interface-and-specified-to-b)